# DDD: Lazy loading in aggregates

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I've been learning DDD for the past few days and struggling to understand some core concepts of aggregate roots. Maybe somebody could give me push in the right direction and elaborate what's best practice in this scenario:

To make this example less complex, let's say we have a domain of two entities: restaurant and opening time. Restaurant is defined as aggregate root.

[image: Text]

From what I understood in all the online examples (correct me if I'm mistaken), the aggregate root is eager loading all sub-entities every time I need an instance of it. So whenever I want to call call a method on the restaurant, all opening times are loaded (no matter if they are used or not).

In this example I want to verify that there is no intersection of opening times when a new time get's added to that restaurant. In this case the eager loading of every other opening time makes sense because I need to compare them with the existing ones.

BUT: this is kind of restricting because I know every time I want to add another collection of something (let's say restaurant images), the SQL load get's heavier and heavier even though most of the methods only require one of the collections.

I could think of two possible solutions:

**Lazy loading**

Lazy loading opening times / sub entities through entity framework property proxies. So the aggregate root can exist without eager loading them but whenever they are needed they can be accessed.
However everywhere I was searching for an answer I've red that lazy loading in aggregate roots is considered bad practice. Maybe somebody could explain why.

**Smaller aggregate roots**

Of course I could define the opening time itself as an aggregate root but then I need to take the business logic (in this case the verification of intersections) outside of the model.

In all the examples above I'm only talking about the command side (not querying or serializing).

Maybe I'm missing some fundamental ideas. How should the aggregate roots be organized in this example and why is lazy loading considered bad practice?

**EDIT**
Not sure why this question was closed because of "opinion based". I'm asking for best practice and why lazy loading is not in this case.

Comment: Your definition of `OpeningTime` seem to be a collection of times, something like a calendar...  I am not sure if it is a good idea to combine Restaurant and Calendar into an aggregate. [this](https://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) might help choosing your aggregates.

Comment: Those two articles were really good and explaining a lot. I wonder why they don't get referenced in all the other DDD lectures I found. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However everywhere I was searching for an answer I've red that lazy loading in aggregate roots is considered bad practice.

That is not exactly the case. The actual restriction is for lazy loading *other aggregates*, due to direct references, at aggregate roots; referring other aggregates with their identifiers is recommended instead. This restriction has very good reasons behind it.

References to aggregates unnecessarily increases application's memory footprint (retrieving an entity that is not going to be used in a transaction); in highly concurrent use cases, where locks are in effect, degrades application performance (unnecessarily locking an entity); hampers data partitioning (both aggregates need to be processed in the same data node).

Each aggregate root defines its own consistency boundary; each transaction is meant to ensure *one aggregate's consistency*. Update operations (or transactions) across aggregates, communicated through *domain events*, are supposed to be *eventually consistent*.

If you are holding direct reference to another aggregate, thereby necessitating lazy loading, and performing updates on them, you should rethink your design.

The choice in your scenario, as usual, depends on the business context or the domain it deals with. If you think *OpeninigTime* is a separate aggregate, with its own consistency boundary, you should hold only its id and publish domain events, containing the id, that the *OpeningTime* aggregate will handle by retrieving the appropriate aggregate. If, however, it is not the case (that seems to be more likely), you may very much hold reference, lazy load, and perform updates on it.

Comment: Great explanation this very much answers the question.

Answer (score 6):

This problem classifies as a set validation problem and there's a few potential solutions depending on the domain needs.

**Strong Consistency**

1. Create an AR to protect the entire set. In the above example if such set has a reasonable length you may create a dedicated `RestaurantSchedule` AR. You may even partition such AR further into `RestaurantWeekSchedule` where you'd have 1 AR for each week. When you want to add/remove opening days it would create/load the AR of the given week. Another option could be to tweak the ORM to load only a subset of the collection e.g. `schedule = scheduleRepo.loadForWeek(openingTime.week()); schedule.add(openingTime);`. Optimistic locking would still allow to detect conflicts.
2. Enforce the rule in the DB. If you have a relational DB for instance you may have `OpeningTime` as an AR and then use unique constraints to prevent violations. The rule would end up living outside the domain, but it may be acceptable. Uniqueness rules aren't that interesting.

**Eventual Consistency**

A very common way to deal with set validation problems is to avoid trying to avoid the violation and focus on detecting and correcting it after the fact either through manual or automated compensating actions. This can be as simple as an exception report that displays overlapping entries or more complex such as a single-threaded listener to `OpeningTimeAdded` events that checks for conflicts and marks such entries for correction.

Comment: I agree that uniqueness rules are not that interesting, in this case I tried to come up with a "simple example" of a rule, but you are absolutely right. Is it correct, that every AR also needs to be an entity that is represented in the database somewhere? Is it really good practice to create an AR to manage collections (in this case RestarantSchedule) that has no ID or representation in the database?

Comment: 1. Aggregate roots are entities themselves. I didn't see any exception so far.
2. If a collection exhibits aggregate behaviors (e.g. represents some domain concept with _intrinsic behaviors_, has continuity of life cycle, requires consistency guarantee, etc.) then introducing one is necessary of course.

Comment: @Nando In the above `RestaurantSchedule` would be stored in the DB as well as `RestaurantWeekSchedule` should you take such partitioning approach. They would be ARs just like any other ARs.

Comment: @Nando Lazy loading any parts of an AR is usually in fact bad practice b/c it's a strong indicator that your AR boundaries are wrong. If you have a large collection that you only have to load for a few AR use cases then the current AR is most likely too large and needs to be broken apart (e.g. `RestaurantSchedule` extracted from `Restaurant`). Eagerly loading a subset of an AR like one of the proposed solutions in my answer is not the same as lazy-loading b/c it guarantees the AR instance will never need more than what was eagerly loaded to perform it's tasks.

Comment: However, if you end up loading just a subset of an AR eagerly, it may be a good indicator that you should perhaps break the AR further apart, such as `RestaurantSchedule` replaced by one schedule per week `RestaurantWeekSchedule` which always get everything eagerly loaded. The distinction is that you will load the right week schedule given the `OpeningTime` entry to manage.

Comment: I understand. This makes sense to me know. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

For your question why is lazy loading considered as bad practice:

Some issue I have with lazy loading is that you need to be constantly aware of potential performance issues. On the other hand However LL is a decent default behaviour for ORMs. It is great if you have long term running applications but it is pointless implementing it on top of your services. I think it depends a lot on the data you are using so its neither good or bad.