# In DDD, can CRUD operations be performed on aggregate entities in isolation of the AR?

Tags: entity, aggregate, domain-driven-design, crud, aggregateroot

Let's say I have a Product entity which has a property called Brand. Brand is an Entity itself (and not a Value Object as it has to be persisted and maintained separately).

I want to be able to create, update or remove brands on a separate UI screen. Then when creating or updating products, assign the right brand through a dropdown list.

Which of the above two entities can be an aggregate root (if not both of them)? And if one should be an AR and the other a dependent entity, how can I perform CRUD operation on them in isolation of the other?

In general, how can this scenario be modeled?

Answer (score 1):

Designating Aggregate Roots depends a great deal on the domain being modelled. As your question claims, *"Brand is an entity itself"* and you want to edit it *"... on a separate UI screen"*, and also want to *"... perform CRUD operation on it in isolation"*. These are strong hints that Brand is an aggregate root itself along with *Product*.

Brand is a property of another aggregate, Product. The recommended way of referencing one aggregate from another is *referencing by identifier*, instead of holding direct references (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60312956/615119) for other reasons of referencing aggregates by id). Therefore, your Product may declare its brand with a Brand id field, unique id referencing the respective Brand, thus enabling editing Product and Brand in isolation. While your Brand editing screen may add new Brands, edit the existing by fetching them with their unique id.

Comment: Many thanks :) Using integer or Guid Ids will be straight forward to persist using ORMs (Entity Framework Core) but if I declare the Id as a value object as recommended by Evans, how can I persist it through an ORM? I've tried to map it but Entity Framework doesn't like it.

Comment: Not an EF Core user myself. Nonetheless, this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects) provides guidelines for implementing value objects in EF Core. Since EF Core 2.0 [owned entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) seems to be the recommended way.