# DDD Aggregate performance issue

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design

I have the following scenario in a project management software: The project manager wants to schedule a task,and so I have built the following aggregate:

```py
class TaskSchedule:
    def __init__(self, task_id, resources, tasks):
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.resources = resources
        self.tasks = tasks
```

The aggregate root would be the task being schedule and for that the aggregate is identified with the task id, and with it I have loaded all the resources needed for that task, all the tasks that are dependencies and all the tasks that have common resource requirements with the task being scheduled.

The rules needed here are:

1. A Task cannot be scheduled with some missing resource requirement
2. A Task cannot be scheduled if some dependency has not been scheduled

The problem here is that as I don't know how many resources/tasks are being load, the retrieving operation for this aggregate can be very expensive.

I have stumbled with the following topics while searching for a solution:

1. **lazy loading**: [DDD: Lazy loading in aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282613/ddd-lazy-loading-in-aggregates). I don't think it is a viable solution because my model would have to, somehow, know how to lazy load its components, which means that the model will have a dependency with the database (no good).
2. **CQRS**: [cant find where I read about it anymore]. I didn't really got the point of it, but by what I have understood I would have to break this operation into queries and commands, but I don't know how to do it and I would have to carry the extra complexity and the eventual consistency along with it. (??)
3. **re-modeling**: The final option is to change the model but in this case I don't see how this could be done.

Am I trapped with this problem? Should I really give up of performance here, or there is an exit to this that I am not aware yet?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a guru in DDD, but I would suggest you to redesign Task aggregate (to make Resources and Subtasks separate aggregates (if they are not yet) and on creation of a new task to request ids of resources and subtasks that belongs to or dependent on it, rather then passing the domain objects) and move your rules related to dependencies and resources to domain service or to application layer so you can check these invariants before actually creating new task. I believe you can go even further in performance improvement by fetching tasks and resources that does not meet the requirements (resources with missing information or unscheduled dependencies), rather than fetching all tasks, and in code check if the quantity of those is not 0, than we are not able to create task.

The main purpose of CQRS (as far as I understand it) is separation of reads (fetching the required info) and writes (any modification of state of your domain objects). With CQRS you can make reads simpler if you pass all the domain logic to writes and keep it consistent and in reads you should be able to map the data retrieved from data source directly to dto since it is consistent, without involving domain objects and underlying logic and invariants check. So this may help you with performance when reading the data from data source, but should not help you when performing commands.

As to lazy loading, I haven`t experience with this yet, so unfortunately I am not able to help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with premature optimisation. If you are sure that loading a Task with resources is already expensive, some commitment  need to be done to achieve better performance. If not, try it. No problem to load all the Task with the dependencies.

An aggregate root must have all the information they need to do the job. Delegate to a Service only when the use case spans across multiple aggregate roots. For example, if you cannot add a resource that have been used for other task.